# How to compile C# for multiple processor machines? (With VS 2010 or csc.exe)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, multicore, compilation

Greetings!

I've searched for compiler (csc.exe) options at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6s2x2bzy.aspx) and I found an answer here, at Stackoverflow, about [compiling **with** multiple processors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939/why-cant-visual-studio-run-on-more-than-one-core-cpu-at-25). But my problem is about compiling **for** multiple processors, as follows.

The university where I'm graduating has a 11 machine cluster (which has 6 quad-cores and 5 four-core bi-processed machines). It runs under linux, but I can install MONO there. And instead of compiling **with** multiple processors or cores, I want to compile **for** multiple processors machine. So:

- Is there any particular detail on how to do it or the CLR on that system should handle the execution to spread it across the cores?
- If there's a way to do this, how can I do it with VS2010 or with csc.exe command line compiler?

*Thanks in advance and I'm sorry if this question makes no sense. I really don't know how to handle multiple cores, as I'm a mere physicist, not a computer scientist!* :)

Comment: Btw., if you consider using anything else than .NET, you'll find much more options for doing distributed computing.

Comment: I wonder that... But until now, C# is the most easy-to-use (compiled) language I've known (in my point of view). I compare it with C, C++, FORTRAN (77, 90, 95), Java, Pascal and Object Pascal. Its simplicity is astonishing. I really want to take some time for C++, but my running against time to finish my Master grad doesn't allow me to do so...

Comment: As you're doing some sort of physics, you might be more interested in an availability of relevant libraries than in a programming language itself. There is a lot of numeric libraries for Fortran, and not that much for .NET. And there are special languages for computing, like Matlab (or Octave), R and Mathematica. Depending on complexity of your problems, you can end up implementing too much of the already existing functionality if you choose a non-specialised language.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of it... I've found some interesting librarys for C# as well... Sorry, but I refuse to use FORTRAN, first of all beacause it's not OO and second because it doesn't allow XML input files... I wouldn't like to write long text files to read it within a program, when I can write meta-data files to do so... MATLAB is a good language as well, it's very fast, but its most for matrix computations... The abstraction of the OO programming is what keeps me to C# or some "not-scientifical" languages (despite the performance compared to a structured language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a cluster, you have to rely on some form of a message-passing parallelism, no compiler will transform your code automatically. At least, a good old MPI is supported: http://osl.iu.edu/research/mpi.net/

Comment: Hey, I've read the MPI description and it seems very cool to work with... But in order to use it, I should install a new Runtime environment, shouldn't I? Besides, the Task Parallel Library cited in the other questions wouldn't handle the problem of multiple cores? - Anyway, thanks for your help and I favorited the MPI website!

Comment: @Girardi, there is a 100% CLI implementation of MPI and a simple wrapper one. For the wrapper you'd only need a compiled native MPI installed (most likely you've got one already), for a managed implementation you don't need anything. TaskParallel library will handle multiple cores, but won't help with multiple nodes, whereas with a message passing you can utilise all of the available cores. Another library used in physics is PVM3, but I've never seen .NET wrappers for it, I only used it with Fortran.

Comment: What is the difference between multi-core and multi-node, in short?

Comment: @Girardi: The former refers to multiple processors within the same machine, where shared memory is used. The latter refers to multiple machines, where a network infrastructure (often called a grid) is used.

Comment: @Girardi, for multi-core (or multi-processor) you've got a shared fast random-access memory. It allows a certain style of programming, implemented in the TaskParallel library and other threads-based approaches. But your cluster is built of a number of nodes, which may share a fast network, but not a single pool of a shared memory. In this case the only programming technique available is message passing. Message passing is very fast when processes are occuping CPU cores of a single node, and reasonably fast when they're on different nodes.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to compile any differently to take account of multiple cores. You need to write your *code* differently though, to use multiple threads. If you can use classes from .NET 4 in your environment (a recent version of Mono should support this) you can use the Task Parallel Library which makes this a bit easier.

Basically you don't get concurrency for free - you have to *think* about which bits of your code can sensibly run in parallel. You might want to read the output of the [Patterns and Practices group for parallel programming](http://parallelpatterns.codeplex.com/). (The book is a very good starting point.)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer... Reading the SK-Logic answer and comments, I came to this doubt of what should I really use... As he said, the TPL only handles multi-cores, not multi-nodes applications...

Answer (score 7):

Your supposition is correct; your question makes no sense.

It is not possible to magically parallelize arbitrary code; you need to modify the code to use multiple threads.

You can use explicitly multiple cores in C# by using the `Thread` or `ThreadPool` classes, or by using Parallel LINQ or the TPL.
There is no special compiler involved.

Comment: In fact, question makes sense. It is possible, in theory, to transform automatically a simple sequential code into a parallel one, and then infer a specialised message-passing protocol for it. Of course, .NET is too complicated for such an inference, but for some kind of a pure functional language it is perfectly possible.

Answer (score 2):

The CLR, by default, will not do anything special to spread the work out across multiple cores. YOU, in developing the application, are responsible for making the best use of your machine's resources. The .NET Framework does have several libraries and technologies that make multithreaded operations simple to implement: look up the Thread class, Delegate.BeginInvoke/EndInvoke, and the Task Parallel Library.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question comes in the form of two seemingly-contradictory statements:

1: It already does

and

2: You can't

Modern operating systems and, thus, development environments, use threads. A thread, fundamentally, represents a single series of sequential steps (and words that *don't* start with "S") that the processor will execute. These threads are managed by the operating system and by the processor architecture, wherein the processor will execute some portion (or all) of a thread, save its state, then switch to another thread.

In the presence of multiple cores (whether by multi-core processors or simply multiple processors or both), it's actually possible for the computer to execute two threads at the same time, assuming that they read and write different locations in memory (threads that utilize the same resources require synchronization, which is a complex ballgame inside this one), by distributing threads across cores.

At the risk of using an overly simplistic simile, think of it this way: your code, as it stands right now, is just a *very* long list of steps to execute to accomplish a particular task. You've now taken this list of instructions into a room full of people (each representing a processing core), and you'd like to use each of these people as efficiently as possible. While a room full of PhD students might have the context and subject-matter knowledge to figure out how to break out your instructions into tasks for each individual person, you've taken your list to a room full of people who are excellent at following directions but entirely stupid when it comes to deduction. In this case, you need to bring a different set of instructions for each person that when *all* of them are executed, you end up with the same result.

Put simply, in order to have your code take advantage of multiple cores or processors, you have to break your work down into small, preferably atomic chunks of code. The specific method that you use to break up your code into multiple threads can vary; using `System.Threading.ThreadPool` or the more recently introduced Task Parallel Library can make some of these things easier, though there's always a tradeoff (as with everything) in either efficiency or control.

Going into much more detail than that would require looking at your actual code. You'd do better finding someone with experience writing solid, performant multithreaded code (if possible, someone with *recent .NET* experience doing this, as this will help make the determination about which libraries would be appropriate).

Comment: Please note that mulithreading won't help here, as OP is asking about a distributed computing.

Comment: @SK-logic: While they're obviously different beasts in application, the design concerns are largely the same: breaking your code down into pieces that can be distributed to multiple processing cores (be they in the same machine or part of a grid).

Comment: @Adam Robinson, the two approaches (the message passing and the shared memory) are *absolutely*  and *incompatibly*  different. And of course all that talk about TaskParallel library and the ThreadPool is absolutely irrelevant and won't help at all, they're not the right tools for this task. And the two models are designed differently, there is a different math behind them.

Comment: @SK: Those who speak in absolutes tend to have blood pressure problems. Like I said, they're different beasts in application. The commonality--and the point that the OP is missing, making it (IMHO) the most relevant portion--is that the instructions must be broken up *by hand*, and not a compiler switch.

Comment: @Adam Robinson, even this is not true. It is possible to do it automatically, depending on your source language. It is a piece of cake with pure functional languages, for example. It is possible to tune a compiler to use either threads or an IPC for the Pi-calculus based languages (like Occam). It is possible, in theory, to parallelise automatically even an imperative code, so it is ok to ask if a compiler can do that already. Unfortunately, such compilers are still purely academical and won't handle C-like languages yet.

Comment: @SK: Until you have a solution for the halting problem, it's impossible to parallelize arbitrary code. Yes, functional languages are designed in such a way that functions are first-class citizens and most data types are immutable (which "solves" the need concurrency), but it's not simply a switch that can be flipped.

Comment: @Adam Robinson, it is intriguing. What is the connection between the halting problem and an automatic parallelisation? And, just for a reference - you can translate any imperative code into pure functional, using a simple SSA-transform. So, whatever is possible for functional code, is possible for any imperative code too. I'm using this technique to identify code blocks that can be translated into an OpenCL or CUDA kernel, but the same can be done for a more complicated parallelism as well.

Comment: @SK: The connection lies in the context of the two issues: In order to parallelize arbitrary code, the compiler will have to go through the same steps as any human would: inspect the code, look for side effects, and decide on either a concurrency-based or stateless model (the latter of which being the only practical option in grid computing scenarios). In order to do this, the naive approach (and, to my knowledge, the only valid approach for *arbitrary* code, since we can't make any contextual assumptions) is a recursive analysis of all code until it reaches some layer of common code (be that

Comment: (cont.) the OS's SDK, a common library set, or the microprocessor's core instruction set along with a map of reserved IO memory locations and interrupt codes) until the full picture can be reached about a particular piece of code. Yes, in some (perhaps many) instances given sufficient time and computing power, a compiler could successfully determine a parallelization scheme for a given piece of code. But to speak as if it's a simple imperitive->functional->parallel shift -- even given theoretical compiler approaches -- is hasty. Maybe one day, but not now.

Comment: @Adam Robinson, an abstract interpretation is more than enough to decide if two flows are independent. And you don't have to follow all the possible flow paths in the abstract interpreter. Fortunately we're not talking about a plain horrible C with a pointer arithmetics, it is a nice managed C#, so no unexpected overlapping memory access is possible. As for "not now" - I've got a working prototype.

Comment: @SK: Sure it is. Who says that my C# code doesn't interact with other (potentially unmanaged) libraries? Who says I'm not using `unsafe` code and doing, as you mention, pointer arithmetic? Who says I'm not interacting with another system over a networking protocol? I'm not saying that you can't qualify code that meets your requirements *and then* parallelize it automatically. I said you can't take *arbitrary* code (which includes all of these inconveniently useful things, like interacting with other, unmanaged libraries and performing IO) and parallelize it.

Comment: @Adam Robinson, it is rather trivial to detect and isolate unsafe things. If a pointer is leaked to the unmanaged world, the whole hierarchy is "tainted". If there is an unknown, un-annotated unmanaged call, the flow branch is tainted. And remember, in practice you'd most likely want to parallelise a numeric code. Normally it is very simple and does not do any of the horrible things you've mentioned - nothing beyond simple array access. No point in parallelising "arbitrary" code, only performance hotspots worth it.

Comment: @SK: You've now changed your argument. My original point was that *you cannot automatically parallelize arbitrary code*. You said: "It is possible, in theory, to parallelise automatically even an imperative code". I said "Until you have a solution for the halting problem, it's impossible to parallelize arbitrary code." You then questioned the relationship between the halting problem and parallelizing arbitrary code (which I've since explained), and now you're changing the rules by referring to code as "tainted". I'm not certain if you work in the academic or commercial

Comment: (cont.) world (and I genuinely don't mean that in a disparaging way), but it seems quite a stretch to refer to external library use or IO operations as "horrible". Unsafe code, yes, that has to be marked `unsafe` for a reason, but the others are perfect valid and *common* things in business applications. Such things must be tuned by something that knows what is going on. My point in this discussion (that arbitrary code can't be automatically parallelized, at least not yet) has not changed; yours, it seems, has.

Comment: @Adam Robinson, yes, you can't automatically parallelise arbitrary code with unknown parts (external libraries, etc.). A live programmer won't be able to do it too. But you can automatically parallelise an arbitrary imperative code, if you've got an access to all of it. And even the presense of pointer arithmetics won't be an issue. I/O is not a problem at all. And nobody is going to parallelise an arbitrary "business application", it is all about scientific computing. As for a "tainted" memory - if there is a random unpredictable access to it, no live programmer can parallelise it too.

Comment: so, this "tainting" thing is for isolating code with an *unknown* behaviour. There is no difference between a compiler and a live programmer, as the black box code behaviour is unknown to both of them.

Comment: @SK: But the point here is that the computer does not have the same perspective as the programmer; the programmer may (and hopefully *does*) know the behavior of the external library and can account for it. And no, parallelization is most decidedly *not* limited to scientific computing. It's a huge issue in commercial development as well. The point here is that it's possible--indeed quite *probable*--that the programmer knows something that the computer doesn't and cannot discover for itself.

Comment: @Adam Robinson, OP is clearly asking about a scientific computing context. How many external libraries you've seen that allows to pass around pointers to large, deep structures? All the interop is always limited to nothning more than arrays. In real world it is not an issue.

Comment: @SK: Again, I said arbitrary code, and you asked me to clarify. I'm confused as to why you'd then continue in a conversation about parallelizing arbitrary code when you agree that it's impossible. If you felt then that what I was talking about was either irrelevant or nonsensical, why not tell me that instead of engaging in a discussion about it? I agree, the OP's clearly talking about a scientific context and what you have going is probably in line with what he needs (you know a good deal more about grid computing than I do; no argument there),

Comment: (cont.) but people who later view this question--and the answers--won't necessarily be coming from that perspective. When they see someone claiming to be able to parallelize code automatically (and then claiming that yes, it works for any arbitrary code), they either need to be aware of your assumptions about the code or be made aware that it's not possible in all (perhaps *most*, when viewed from a larger scale) cases.

Comment: @Adam Robinson, my point is that it is still possible to parallelise automatically an *arbitrary*  code even if nothing is known about a large part of it. I'm not talking about the *best possible*  parallelisation, of course. And, as a modern code is much less spaghetti-like than it used to be, all your concerns are not that scary. You know nothing about a part of a code, and you don't care - you still can parallelise a code which depend on data unavailable to the unknown part. That's it. So, in *most*  real-world cases it is perfectly possible to do the automatic parallelisation.